# How do I include custom header files in my C++ file in linux?

Tags: debian, header-files, c++

I am new to linux and have some question regarding inclusion of header files. I have created a `blinkled.cpp` file using nano editor and then I wrote a simple program to blink an LED using BeagleBoneBlack.

For this operation, I specifically configured the GPIO pins such as - exported the pin, set its direction, read/write its value and unexported the pin. Now, I have found a .cpp source file and .h file which has all the GPIO configuration functions.

I have downloaded this from online and at present, the .cpp and .h files are in the downloads directory. I would like to include these files as header in my `blinkled.cpp` file and use GPIO functions to configure the GPIO pins. So, how do I do this?

Can I just specify the path of the .cpp and .h files to include them in my `blinkled.cpp` file or there's more to it? Any advice and information regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably do something like

1. include the header file that you found at the top of your source file, with a statement like `#include "foundfile.h"`
2. compile and link the found source file together with yours into a single executable, like `g++ -o blinkled blinkled.cpp foundfile.cpp`

This assumes all three files are in the same directory where you are executing the `g++` command from.

See for example 
[GCC and Make
Compiling, Linking and Building
C/C++ Applications](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)
 or any equivalent tutorial.

Comment: I am familiar with the point 1. Regarding point 2, to compile and get the executable in the terminal, generally I use **arm-linux-gnueabhif-g++ blinkled.cpp -o blinkled**. So are you saying, I should do this **arm-linux-gnueabhif-g++ blinkled.cpp foundflie.cpp -o blinkled foundfile**?. Will check the link too.

Comment: @PsychedGuy no, you have added an extraneous `foundfile` argument on to the end

Comment: Ok will **arm-linux-gnueabhif-g++ blinkled.cpp foundfile.cpp -o blinkled** do?. As this will generate a single executable file **blinkled** along with foundfile included, like you said.

Comment: @PsychedGuy you will need to try it and see: other (system) libraries may need to be linked and/or header files/paths provided - depending on the implementation of the code you downloaded.

Comment: Found the solution based on your inputs. Just to avoid including the path in "include", I created a folder and copied the blinkled.cpp, (foundfile)SimpleGPIO.cpp and SImpleGPIO.h into one folder and then included it in my blinkled.cpp file as "include SimpleGPIO.h". Then I complied it as **arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ blinkledled.cpp SimpleGPIO.cpp -o blinky**. The blinky is the executable to be deployed on my BBB. I don't understand why there's a downvote for your answer, anyways, it was helpful. Thanks!